# how to make sure that the token comes from the device or browser that logged in

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am developing a web api with C #.

To login I'm using bear, I put user data and it returns a token, this token that I placed in the header to identify the user, it works very well.

Problem

Normally, tokens are stored in the cooks and in the local store, and a wrongdoer can copy the token and take it to the other device and he will have access to the account.

How do I certify that this token is being used by the device or browser that logged in?

Comment: Reading this post can help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264325/web-api-oauth-bearer-token-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264325/web-api-oauth-bearer-token-security)

Comment: Reading this post can help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264325/web-api-oauth-bearer-token-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264325/web-api-oauth-bearer-token-security)

Answer (score 1):

You can, but they **aren't very effective**. Hijacking cookies can be done if someone has access to the victim's computer or if the traffic is non-encrypted (HTTP). There are a few steps you could do as countermeasures.

If you are attaching the token to a session you could **change session timeouts**, although this also makes it harder to use your service continuously. This is what internet banks use, usually a 4-5 minute window.

Use **different tokens for each device**, if the token is being used somewhere else don't allow authentication. You could use them in combination with sessions, keep the session short and if you see two authentication tokens with different session ids then you know there's been a breach on that account, logout those devices. This is how most modern services work like, because you can keep the user logged in indefinitely and you can also logout individual devices.

As for how to distinguish devices it's impossible unless you are writing your own desktop/mobile application. You could use IP, but that could change or the attacker might have the same IP. Desktop applications usually rely on **hardware devices** connected, this is how for example the Windows license is tied to your machine. But these can be manipulated or even emulated, worst case the user unplugs the mouse and gets logged out. So using hardware ids is much harder, as far as I know Microsoft uses machine learning to determine whether you're changing video cards or migrating your license to your grandma's computer.

And the best would be to use a different medium for authentication, such as sending out SMS or Email, but in the end you have to **trade off usability and security** and that all depends on the kind of service you want to offer. If you're handling purchases then two factor is a must, at least when making the purchase.